# How can I set values to a column of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

For example,

I got a `df` like:

```
    x    y
A   1    1
B   2    2
C   3    3
```

I want to change column 'y' values like this:

```
    x    y
A   1    56
B   2    45
C   3    34
```

I had the values in an array `a = [56, 45, 34]`

I can change the values using .set_value:

```
df.set_value('A', 'y', a[0])
df.set_value('B', 'y', a[1])  
df.set_value('C', 'y', a[2])
```

But if `df` is array, I can do:

```
df[:, 1] = a
```

Is there a way like the above for setting values to a column of DataFrame?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df.loc[:, 'Y'] = a
```

This should set (all index, column 'Y') of df to Array a, without the [SettingWithCopyWarning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) message. This is also the recommended way according to pandas-doc.

Comment: @Alex Cio, I'm still a little new here so.. Can you give an example on what kind of information I should add for the above?

Comment: No problem man! I am talking about an explanation, not just leaving a snippet so that others might understand what you though when postig your code

Answer (score 2):

Creating dataframe:

```
df
Out[]: 
   x  y
A  1  1
B  2  2
C  3  3
```

You can use iloc function and pass array to it as follows:

```
df['y'].iloc[0:3]=[56, 45, 34]

df
Out[]: 
   x   y
A  1  56
B  2  45
C  3  34
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the following:

```
df['Y'] = a
```

Comment: Worth flagging potential setting on a copy: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy